# How make my CSS responsive using Bootstrap 3.1

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wrote a page with some CSS. Now I need to make it responsive using Bootstrap. But I'm new to bootstrap.

I just need to know, how to make my CSS responsive with Bootstrap 3.1. My CSS is mostly inline:

```
.slider_size{width:750px; height:400px;; float:left;}
.right_banner{width: 400px; float: right;  overflow: hidden; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0 ;}
.cBoth{clear: both;}
.fleft{ float:left;}
.cbm5{ clear:both;}
.cat_mid{width: 25%  !important; float: left; padding: 10px  !important; text-align: center; border: 1px;}
.mid_cat_br{width: 100%; border: 1px solid #cfe2f1; height: 400px;}
```

Comment: Nope. I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: Responsive is not a on/off switch. You need to learn more: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Comment: @jay Just i need to make my web site responsive....this is my css for some content...and i also use bootstrap....so what should i need to change in my this css....else any other idea...can you give me...pls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you may want to think about redoing your site using twitter bootstrap and not your original css. I also noticed that your css does not use any of the classes used in bootstrap which means that your html will need major changes in order to use bootstrap's framework. So with that said you may need to start from ground zero. This is kind of an example of why a responsive first approach is necessary. GOOD LUCK!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you gave a lot of your elements explicit pixel widths, which will keep them from being responsive. Also, from the code above, it doesn't look like you're using any of the built-in Bootstrap classes. 
Bootstrap is designed to be responsive out of the box, but you do still need to use its div structures and CSS in order for that to work. Check out http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples and download their source code to use as a template.

Comment: From your comments, it sounds like maybe you should read a bit more about Bootstrap. Because it's a framework, you can't just include their CSS in the head of your page and let it do magic, you'll have to use the Bootstrap classes and HTML structure within your site.

Answer (score 2):

As others mentioned, making a website responsive isn't a simple matter of editing a few lines of CSS. The beauty of Twitter Bootstrap is leveraging the responsiveness it has out of the box. My suggestion is to spend some time learning the Bootstrap foundation and fundamentals. Microsoft offers a fantastic free online class "Building Responsive UI with Bootstrap" through the Microsoft Virtual Academy. Check it out:

[Microsoft Virtual Academy](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Although you have accepted an answer I would like to help you by breaking down your CSS code elements.

```
.slider_size{width:750px; height:400px;; float:left;}
```

I am assuming it's a simple slider; you can replace it with built in slider provided in Bootstrap [(bootstrap carousel slider)](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp)

```
.right_banner{...}
```

For Right Align you can use this class `align-right`

And so on. Basically you do less with the build-in classes given by bootstrap. So rebuilding or editing your site should not take a lot of time.